# How to store & retrieve to display emoji on Room database (Android Studio)

Tags: android, database, android-room, emoji

I am building a mood tracker android application using Room database with Java language.
I am planning to use android built-in emojis for the user to input their desired emoji, but I am not sure how to store it in the Room db and then retrieve the data to display in another fragment?

Will really appreciate if someone could provide some guidance on this or attach relevant tutorial video links about it because I am still new to mobile app development

Answer (score 1):

As far as Room is concerned you only need to store some means of knowing what the emoji is, perhaps the Unicode for the emoji.

e.g. grinning face is 0x1F600, perhaps a descriptive. You can then set a TextView, as an example, incorporating the emoji.

Perhaps you could have a table just containing the emoji's and then store a reference (have a relationship) to this table.

**A very simple working Room example follows.**

The result will be a list of emoji's displayed in a ListView.

This example has a table that stores the emoji codes along with a description of the emoji . The table has been named **emoji** and the Entity class is **EmojiTable** as per :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "emoji")
class EmojiTable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    Long id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "emoji_code", index = true)
    String emoji_code;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "emojidesc")
    String emoji_desc;

    // Default constructor
    EmojiTable(){}

    // Alternative Constructor
    @Ignore
    EmojiTable(String emoji_code,String emoji_desc) {
        this.emoji_code = emoji_code;
        this.emoji_desc = emoji_desc;
    }

    // Override default toString method to return the emoji followed by it's decsription
    @Ignore
    public String toString() {
        return new String(Character.toChars(Integer.decode(emoji_code))) + " " + emoji_desc;
    }
}
```

- 3 columns

  - the **_id** column for a unique identifier
  - the **emoji_code** column for the hex code of the emoji
  - the **emoji_desc** column for a description of the emoji
- Note the **toString** method has been overidden to return a string containing the emoji followed by it's description. This is used to set the TextView in the ListView.

  - otherwise the default **toString** method is used which displays the object.

To accompany the emoji table the DAO **AllDao** for the database actions :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {
    
    // Insertion of a row
    @Insert(entity = EmojiTable.class, onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    long insertEmoji(EmojiTable e);
    //Deletion of ALL rows
    @Query("DELETE FROM emoji")
    int deleteAll();
    // Get ALL rows
    @Query("SELECT * FROM emoji")
    List<EmojiTable> getAllEmojis();
    // Get a row by the id passed to the method 
    @Query("SELECT * FROM emoji WHERE emoji._id = :id")
    EmojiTable getEmojiById(Long id);
    // Get the number of rows (used to detect changes)
    @Query("SELECT count(*) FROM emoji")
    Long getRowsInEmojiTable();
}
```

The @Database abstract class **MyDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = {EmojiTable.class}, version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();
}
```

A class, namely EmojiList that defines emoji's/ master list of emoji's.

- using this changes (if the number of emoji's changes) allows the emoji's stored in the database to be changed (should a new version of the App be deployed).

.

```
class EmojiList {

    public static final EmojiTable[] EMOJIS =  {
            new EmojiTable("0x1F600","Grinning Face"),
            new EmojiTable("0x1F602","Unknown"),
            new EmojiTable("0x1F911","Money-Mouth Face")
    };
}
```

- 3 emoji's defined

The Layout that includes a ListView for display of the List of Emoji's :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/emojilist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

- Nothing special here other than a background colour to see where the list is.

Finally putting it all together the Activity **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;
    List<EmojiTable> emojiList_list;
    ListView emojiList_listview;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        // Instantiate the MyDatabase object with a built Room Database
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this,MyDatabase.class,"mydb")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
        // Instantiate the dao interface
        dao = db.getAllDao();
        // Check to see if the emoji's stored equals the master list
        // If not rebuild the emjoi table
        if (dao.getRowsInEmojiTable() != EmojiList.EMOJIS.length) {
            dao.deleteAll(); // Delete all existing rows
            for(EmojiTable e: EmojiList.EMOJIS) {
                dao.insertEmoji(e);
            }
        }
        // Very simple list of all emojis
        emojiList_list = dao.getAllEmojis(); // 
        emojiList_listview = this.findViewById(R.id.emojilist);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,emojiList_list);
        emojiList_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Result**

When run the App looks like :-

[image]

The database (via Database Inspector) :-

[image]